# Available on 0 of 0 channels and apps but it is lising in restapi why?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have a mobile storefront android App designed using restAPI for my shopify store. when I make the products unavailable in the app through the products page in shopify back-end, The mobile storefront still shows the products made unavailable.. Why does this happen & is there any way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use "published_status=published" example   https://shopname.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-04/products.json?published_status=published